# ¿Cómo mostrar imagenes de la base de datos en mi página web usando php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando mostrar unas imagenes, que se encuentran en la base de datos, a mi página web, pero no logro conseguirlo. Esto es una de las pruebas que he intentado:

Código php:

```
<?php

 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "***");
 // $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` as p INNER JOIN posts_contenido as c ON p.id_post = c.id";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
 $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 echo "<table>";
 if($resultCheck > 0){

     while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

         echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>";
              ?> <img alt ="database_img" src ="<?php echo $fila["url_img"]; ?>" height="100" width="100">
             <?php echo "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
     }

 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Lo que tengo en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me sale por pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Revisa en el html de la página cuál es la ruta a la imagen y compara con la ruta relativa desde tu php. Coincide con la ruta donde puedes encontrar las imágenes?

Comment: @Alfabravo Buenas, en la página pulsado Ctrl + U, veo que tengo esta ruta: <img alt ="database_img" src ="./img/blog/18/2019_05_02.jpg">. Aunque no sé porque me sale el punto antes de /img

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Probaste completando la URL con el prefijo de tu dominio, poniendo delante algo como `http://www.tudominio.com`, seguido del resto de la ruta de la imagen? Si no funciona haz un `echo` también aparte, fuera del `src`, copia y pega en el navegador a ver si es un problema en los datos mismos que son erróneos.

Comment: Y el punto sale ¡porque existe en tus datos! Revisa la captura de pantalla que pusiste, cuando se agranda, se ve que las rutas de imágenes empiezan por el punto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Buenas!. Cierto, no funciona, algo de mi ruta está mal, me voy a centrar en eso que seguramente es el fallo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Imprime la ruta con el dominio, y prueba si quitándole el punto funciona. Si funciona entonces lo que tienes que hacer es actualizar los registros, quitándole el punto que tienen delante en la url.

Comment: @A.Cedano Veo que algo falla con la ruta que tengo, debe ser por lo que me comentaste, voy a ver como solucionarlo. Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: La respuesta va en la parte de abajo y no en tu pregunta, tampoco le coloques solucionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas al final he podido arreglarlo, no era un fallo del código que estuviera mal, sino que la url que tenia no era la correcta. Simplemete le acabe añadiendo ../../

Dejo la pregunta y la respuesta por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo, y piensa que el fallo es en el código, que se fije en la url.

Este seria un ejemplo de como me funciona:

```
<a href="/<?php echo $lang; ?>/blog/<?php echo $page;?>/<?php echo $fila['id'];?>"><img  alt="database_img" src="../../admin-blog/<?php echo $fila['url_img'];?>" height="100" width="100" "></a>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Cuanto te deje la página, marca la respuesta como válida, así aparece arriba y se ve mejor. Para ello con darle al tick que te sale a la izquierda, bajo la votación, basta. Un saludo.

Comment: @JoseManuelMorales Hola! Sí, cuando me permita, pone en dos días, la marcaré. Saludos!

Comment: No tienes que poner `[SOLUCIONADO]` en el título de la pregunta, Stackoverflow no funciona como un foro, lo que indica que un problema ha sido solucionado es que hay una respuesta que está marcada como aceptada. Y, cuando alguien te ayude a encontrar el error, por deferencia lo correcto es invitar a esa persona a escribir una respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si la carpeta img se encuentra en el raiz de tu proyecto debes quitar ./ de la url de la imagen.

Puedes quitar ./ de la siguiente forma:

```
    $posicion = strpos($fila["url_img"], './');
    if ($posicion !== false) { 
        echo substr($fila["url_img"], $posicion + 2)); 
    } else {
        echo $fila["url_img"];
    }
```

Comment: Buenas! En mi caso el fallo era la url que tenia, le he añadido ../../ y queda tal que así. ../../admin-blog/./img/blog/14/2019_05_02.jpg. De esta manera me funciona.